# Where is Electron (or Chrome) saving the zoom setting?

Tags: google-chrome, electron

In my electron app menu I am using the built-in zoomin/zoomout roles. (The menu code being used is pasted in at the end of this question.)  I start the app, choose zoom-in, then close the app. When I start it again, it starts at that already zoomed in setting.

Where is it saving this configuration? There is no hidden file being created or modified in the application directory, or below. I wondered if it might be something about my development environment, so I built the Linux package, and ran that, but the behaviour is the same.

Another question I've had is where the Chrome debugger saves the breakpoints (and other debug configuration) between runs of my electron app, and now I'm wondering if the zoom setting is also a Chrome thing? However, I've checked and it appears to be saving these settings per-application: if I set the zoom in the development environment, it has not affected the zoom when I start the packaged version.

(To be clear, this is not a bug I'm trying to fix - in fact I'd class it as a feature - but I would like to understand what setting files my Electron app is reading/writing, beyond the ones I am explicitly creating.)

```
{
  label: 'View',
  submenu: [
    {role:'resetzoom'},
    {role:'zoomin'},
    {role:'zoomout'},
    {type:'separator'},
    {role:'togglefullscreen'},
    ]
  }
```